# Syntax for adding constraints to Fluent/Eloquent query

Tags: syntax, laravel-4, eloquent, fluent

I have seen both of these syntaxes for adding constraints to an existing Fluent/Eloquent $query (such as when appending a constraint based on a conditional):

```
$query = $query->where( 'id','=',1 );
```

and

```
$query->where( 'id','=',1 );
```

Is there any practical difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No difference at all. In this case $query is an object and it will internally set the filter, but it also returns itself, to provide chaining:

```
$query->where( 'id','=',1 )->where( 'name','=', 'antonio' );
```

So those two are exactly the same.

```
$query = $query->where( 'id','=',1 );
$query->where( 'id','=',1 );
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was hoping.  Wouldn't adding the redundant assignment technically add a tick or two to the processing time?

Comment: Oh, yes, it might, but this is an object and objects are referenced by it's pointers (address in memory), so it would be really just a tick.